# Nginx CORS settings

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, nginx, cors

I run a very simple home-grown PHP router on my Nginx server which services requests from my Android app.  The method calls are typically along the lines of

```
https://example.com/lua/path/to/method
```

e.g.

```
https://example.com/lua/logerror/errormsg

https://example.com/lua/recordscore/scoredata
```

The `lua` bit there is largely historical - the underlying router is in fact PHP.  Up until now I have been able to use the following Nginx configuration block

```
location /lua
{
 if (!-e $request_filename) {rewrite ^/(.*)$ /lua/index.php?$1 last;}
}
```

From within my app these requests are issued as `XMLHttpRequests`.

However a recent upgrade to Chrome - the Android webview used by my Cordova/Android app is (since Android 6) updated at pretty much the same time as Chrome gets updates - has upset the apple cart.  Now when I debug my app via `chrome://inspect` I find error messages along the lines of

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/lua/logerror/Zooming'
> from origin 'file://' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

---

I also use the newer `fetch` API where I have been able to fix the issue by configuring the fetch with

```
{mode:'no-cors',cache:'no-cache',credentials:'omit'}
```

However, changing everying to use `fetch` is not a straightforward option.

---

I thought I might be able to fix this by changing the Nginx configuration block above to

```
location /lua
{
 add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;   
 if (!-e $request_filename) {rewrite ^/(.*)$ /lua/index.php?$1 last;}
}
```

but this is has not helped.  My knowledge of Nginx configuration is inadequate to help me establish just how I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the CORS configuration I'm currently using for NGINX. You should be able to fix your issue by replacing your `add_header` attempt with it.

```
 if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
 }
 if ($request_method = 'POST') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
 if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
```

**WARNING**: i used *, but you can - and should - always limit those rules to a more restrictive domain/subdomain list, unless you really want to enforce a wide-open CORS policy (and you're fully aware of the risks).

Since it's a pretty long piece of code, you might want to put this on a separate file (such as /etc/nginx/cors-settings.conf) and then include it with the following one-liner:

```
include /etc/nginx/cors-settings.conf;
```

**EDIT**: You asked for NGINX Cors settings, but it might be possible that the Chrome warning you're seeing has little to do with it. It could be also due to the fact that you're using a Chrome Extension that is trying to perform cross origin resource sharing without configuring its manifest.json file in the proper way. If your problem persist, I would first try to reproduce it with Incognito mode, and then - if the problem doesn't show there - I would deactivate the Chrome Extensions (one at a time) in order to find the culprit.

If you find the "offending" extension, you can then check its **manifest.json** file to see if it contains something like this:

```
"permissions": [
   "http://*/"
 ]
```

If there's nothing like that, I would then contact the author and notify him/her about the issue.